# How to Convert a simple SELECT Statement into SQL SERVER AGENT JOB for schedule and Auto Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

How can I convert a simple select statement into SQL SERVER AGENT JOB for an auto Email to an operator. e.g. `USE [DYNAMICS] select * from ACTIVITY` I daily need this ACTIVITY table contents at 10:00am via Email. How I'll do it as auto Email from SQL SERVER AGENT? Help required.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: What were wrong with the examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)?

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER have a function sp_send_dbmail that will help.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Configure your server:

```
execute sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
reconfigure
execute sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1
reconfigure
```

Configure your account:

```
execute msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',
@port = 587,
@enable_ssl = 1,
@account_name = 'mail_account', 
@display_name = 'SQL SERVER',
@email_address = 'your@email.com',
@username = 'your@login',
@password = '*** password ***'

execute msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
    @profile_name = 'mail_profile',
    @description = 'Mail notification by SQL.'

execute msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
    @profile_name = 'mail_profile',
    @account_name = 'mail_account',
    @sequence_number = 1
```

Send mail

```
execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'MAIL NAME',
    @recipients = 'mailto@mailto.com',
    @subject = 'subject',
    @body = 'your message'
```

Thats all!

Comment: Email is configured and it is sending me Emails when a task is completed or failure. I need to a execute a SELECT statement and then I need the results/report of that select statement on my Email. How I will do that? How I will get that report in .txt or some other format?

Comment: There's an explanation in that link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-sending-an-html-e-mail-message